# Не правильно выводится время на сайте

Tags: время, datetime, timezone

При разработке сайта требуется выводить время.
В базу Datetime время пишется верно по Москве UTC+3, Установки timezone Europe/Moscow.
На локальном опен сервер выводится как должно быть.
При переносе на хостинг centos 6 показывает время на час больше.
Тех поддержка хостинга усердно заявляет, что у них все в порядке.
В чем может быть проблема?
Сайт на Cake PHP 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду время локальное, для пользователя (то есть пользователь в Москве будет видеть московское время, а человек из Хабаровска, GMT+10, то:

1. На сервере, записывайте время с индикатором часового пояса. Причем совершенно не важно, какой часовой пояс: может быть UTC, может пояс сервера, может просто какой-то фиксированный.
2. Проверяйте, что пояс присутствует везде, когда сервер работает со временем. Особенно важно, чтобы клиент получал время с часовым поясом (см. ISO 8601).
3. Уже на стороне клиента (то есть с JavaScript если это браузер), время трансформируется в зависимости от того, где находится клиент, и в зависимости от того, что именно нужно показать, к примеру «две минуты назад» или «Сегодня, 15:46».

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В моем случае все немного проще, Как сказал время пишется в базу по Москве, а отображаться может в зависимости от установленного пояса выбранного клиентом города как вы указали в п.2. Мой вопрос был немного другой, что именно Московское время на локальном сервере отображается как нужно, а при переносе сайта на хостинг начинает показывать на час больше. И сам вопрос в чем тут может быть проблема. В настройках сервера или еще в чем?

Comment: Проблема в том, как вы записываете время. Скорее всего, оно записано без часового пояса. Поэтому на московском сервере это «случайно» работает, но на других, может не работать. И проблема тут не в конфигурации сервера, а именно в самом приложении, которое записывает только часть времени.

Comment: <pre>'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {
  'time' => '2020-05-05T05:37:57+03:00',
  'timezone' => 'Europe/Moscow',
  'fixedNowTime' => false
 
 }</pre> - Время из базы поступает в таком виде

Comment: У вас часовой пояс записан дважды: в самой дате, в форме `+03:00` и в `timezone`. Скорее всего ошибка связанна с этим. Сотрите `timezone` и используйте часовой пояс из самой даты ISO 8601.

Comment: Гениально! Заменил запись в БД по UTC, вывод сделал по Europe/Moscow. Теперь время выводится и на локальном и на боевом как нужно. Видимо действительно произошло задвоение установок во времени и в timezone. Спасибо, очень помогли!